# Run command line with two different sets of arguments

Tags: node.js

Let's say I have a node script runner that has it's own set of arguments e.g.

`npx hardhat run -arg1 -arg2 /scr/CLI.js (the script to run)`

but that script has its own set of arguments e.g.

`npx hardhat run -arg1 /src/CLI.js -argForCLI`

If I try to do this I will get an error regarding unrecognised arguments pertaining to the `npx hardhat run` when they are actually intended for the script itself, how can I use two sets of arguments at the same time so the above line will work?

Comment: I assume `run -arg1 -arg2 /src/CLI.js` are parameters for the `hardhat` runner and passed into that runner. So you must look in the the docs of hardhat how to pass parameters to the called script. npm does this with `--` to separate the parameters for npm from the parameters for the called script. Ie something like `npx hardhat run -arg1 /src/CLI.js -- -argForCLI` Maybe hardhat has implemented something similar.

Comment: You can try to separate them with a `--` by doing `npx hardhat run -arg1 -- /src/CLI.js -argForCLI`